# delete row from table where column does not exist in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this SQL query that deletes a user's preferences from USERPREF table if they have not logged in for 30 days (last login date located in MOMUSER table), however, it does not verify that the user still exists in MOMUSER. How can I change this so that if USERPREF.CUSER does not exist in MOMUSER.CODE that the USERPREF row is also deleted in that situation since they will not have a last login date?

```
    DELETE USERPREF FROM USERPREF
    INNER JOIN MOMUSER ON MOMUSER.CODE = USERPREF.CUSER
    WHERE MOMUSER.LOG_START < GETDATE()-30
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to an *outer* join, reverse the condition (so you match users you want to *keep*) and move it into the join, then use `IS NULL` to delete rows *without* joins:

```
DELETE USERPREF
FROM USERPREF
LEFT JOIN MOMUSER ON MOMUSER.CODE = USERPREF.CUSER
    AND MOMUSER.LOG_START >= GETDATE()-30
WHERE MOMUSER.LOG_START IS NULL
```

Recall that an outer join returns all nulls when the join misses. By moving the date condition into the join, you get to exercise it but *not* require a joined row. The where clause filters out all rows that have the kind of data you want to keep - leaving only those you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% I understand your question but I think that you might be looking for a `left join` and check if `MOMUSER.LOG IS NULL` (should be null if it didn't actually join

```
DELETE USERPREF FROM USERPREF
LEFT JOIN MOMUSER ON MOMUSER.CODE = USERPREF.CUSER
WHERE MOMUSER.LOG_START < GETDATE()-30
OR MOMUSER.LOG_START IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE  FROM USERPREF u
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM MOMUSER MOMUSER
                   WHERE MOMUSER.CODE = u.CUSER AND  MOMUSER.LOG_START < GETDATE()-30)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension to Seth Answer but using cte.Remeber **and** clause in join eliminates the values before joining

```
with cte
    as
    (
    select 
    *
    from USERPREF up
    left join
    MOMUSER  mu
    on 
    mu.CODE = up.CUSER
    and MOMUSER.LOG_START >= GETDATE()-30
    where MOMUSER.LOG_START IS NULL
    )
    ---select * from cte
    delete from cte
```